# How to access values(an array) from specific Field of ThingSpeak channel?

Tags: python, matlab, csv, iot

I am unable to access data from field which contains the array of values with error as Not a Number(NaN). These values were stored in a buffer before sending as the website can be accessed only once in 15 mins.  Do I have to follow any specific method to send data from my RaspberryPi ( using Python) while using buffer values (stored values)?

Attached the screenshot of the values received by ThingSpeak ( CSV file). Is there any way to send multiple values to a field by accessing it once in 15 seconds.

[Screenshot of CSV file generated with ThingSpeak](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hwqIr.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not able to post a reply to your question, but I wanted to ask a follow-up question. Are you trying to read multiple values from a ThingSpeak channel using MATLAB and this is where you are seeing NaN? If so, I can walk you through it.

I created a ThingSpeak channel and stored 4, 8, 15, 16, 23, and 42 in it as [4 8 15 16 23 42]. ThingSpeak stores data in a channel as a string up to 255 characters.

Here's the channel feed: https://api.thingspeak.com/channels/228314/fields/1/last.json

In MATLAB, use the following code to get the data back out of the ThingSpeak channel and use it as a normal vector.

```
fieldData = webread('https://api.thingspeak.com/channels/228314/fields/1/last.json')
field1Vector = str2num(fieldData.field1)
field1Vector(1)
```

If you do not have str2num in your version of MATLAB, you can use eval in the same way.

Comment: I am reading it in thingSpeak website itself. With your code I was able to retrieve data after data was made **public**.

Comment: ' fieldData = webread('https ://api.thingspeak. com/channels/ChannelD/feeds/last.json?results=1&api_key=[API_KEY]') ' modified the url to access private channel.

Comment: That looks correct with private channels. I am glad the solution helped you.